# ReactJS changing styles with const strings

Tags: css, reactjs

Hi I am trying to change the styles of a component using a const string but it does not work. May I know why this approach is wrong?

```
 style={{ color: {newColor} }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use brackets again

```
style={{ color: newColor }}
```